# What's the Maximum Number of Local Minima an Nth-Order Polynomial Surface or Solid Can Have?

Tags: polynomials, optimization, 3d, maxima-minima

I have an optimization problem that in the ideal case can be approximated by a 3D polynomial surface, i.e.
$$f_{n}\left(x,y\right)=\sum _{i,j\leq{n}} C_{i,j}x^{i}y^{j}$$
My assumptions are:

1. All minima are encompassed over my scanned space along $x$ and $y$.
2. The data and apparent minima can be approximated well with a smooth surface, which is not flat.
3. For any $n^{th}$ order fit, the surface must have one or more global minima.

From criteria 2.), for instance, for $2^{nd}$ order (quadratic fits), we can disqualify all functions of the forms $C_{2,0}x^2-C_{0,2}y^2...$ and $C_{2,0}y^2-C_{0,2}x^2...$ ([hyperbolic parabaloids](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicParaboloid.html)).  Likewise we can eliminate fits that lack either x or y terms and fits which produce imaginary solutions.

In the simple case, the surface can be approximated by [a quadratic](https://web.archive.org/web/20160830021258/http://mathinsight.org/local_extrema_introduction_two_variables) and probably looks something like this:
[image]

However, for more complicated systems, I expect my objective function to produce multiple relative minima.  Further, in some cases I may need to expand my objective function into z as well, and fit to $f_{n}\left(x,y,z\right)=\sum _{i,j,k\leq{n}} C_{i,j}x^{i}y^{j}z^{k}$ with similar criteria (at edges goes to $\infty$ or constant value, never $-\infty$; has at least 1 global minima)

With that in mind, my questions are:

1. What is the maximum number of relative minima for $n^{th}$ polynomial surfaces meeting my criteria?
2. If fitting to $f_{n}\left(x,y,z\right)=\sum _{i,j,k\leq{n}} C_{i,j}x^{i}y^{j}z^{k}$ what is the maximum number of relative minima for $n^{th}$ polynomial solids meeting the criteria?

It seems like surely there is an elementary answer to the above.  However, I've been having trouble finding pertinent discussions/lectures, save for a couple regarding [$n^{th}$ order polynomials of a single variable](https://web.archive.org/web/20160830031540/https://socratic.org/questions/how-many-local-extrema-can-a-cubic-function-have), which can have a maximum of $n-1$ minima.

Also from some freeform exploration of polynomials on Wolfram Alpha, I know that you can at least have 2 minima for a $4^{th}$ order polynomial surface, such as [$z=x^{4}+y^{4}-y^{3}+x^{3}-x^{2}-y^{2}-x-y$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?x=0&y=0&i=z%3Dx%5E4%2By%5E4-y%5E3%2Bx%5E3-x%5E2-y%5E2-x-y). (Update: [$z=x^{4}+y^{4}-y^{3}+x^{3}-x^{2}-y^{2}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?x=0&y=0&i=local%20minima%20of%20z%3Dx%5E4%2By%5E4-y%5E3%2Bx%5E3-x%5E2-y%5E2) has 4 minima, so clearly the maximum number of minima for an $n^{th}$ order polynomial must be at least $n$.)

Comment: Also if you restrict yourself to systems of equations, the number of local minima grows exponentially in the dimension of the polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of local minima is infinite, at least for polynomial of degree more than $4$. For instance, consider the $4$ degree polynomial

$$ p(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2 - 1)^2.$$
Every point in the unit circle is a minimum of $p$ and there is an infinite amount of them (even non countable).

Comment: Ah, I should have specified more explicitly, I'm asking about true local minima with respect to curvature in x and y wrt to z.  Your solution actually has no local minima that pass the Second derivative test.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html

What's the maxima local minima if those minima must pass the second derivative test w/ D > 0 and fxx(x0,y0)>0?